# create a function in SQL that formats ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to some tips on how to make a function that formats an ID in the format YYDDMM-XXXX.

And returns the same ID in the format YYYYMMDDXXXX. Example and ID can be 850101-1122 as inparameter in the function but I want to return as 198501011122 without having to hardcode '19' + . Because in the future some of the systems persons might be born in 2000 +.

Thanks!

Comment: And how do you know if someone is born in 1913 or in 2013 ? Where do you want to set the limit ?

Comment: Actually without having to use hardcoding. Should be possible, limit is that a person has to be atleast 18 years old.

Comment: we can't tell by only that right? if atleast 18 years old you want to set it to 20XX instead of 19XX, how if the person > 100 years old? just in case :)

Comment: yes that is true also, but in that case I've got a function that counts a persons age already. So in that case we can do if Function_Age > 100 then '19'. But that also would be hardcoded

Comment: You've basically got two choices: 1) Treat the century as "19xx" if YY <= 50, or 2) Adopt a four (or even three) digit "YYYY" format.

Comment: Yes that is true, should be possible to variable century -1 + ID else variable century + ID. Since YYYY = Year person is born.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, assuming you have a function that calculates the age and assuming the length and format is always the same, you can use this to determine the first 2 characters of the year:

```
case when age > year(getdate())-2000 
                then '19' 
                else '20' end
```

So if the age is greater than the current year - 2000 (14 in this case) then you want 19XX, otherwise it's 20XX.

Next you can use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx) to swap the `DD` and `MM` parts around and build up the final value.

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37f87/2)

### Create Script

```
create table userid_table (id nvarchar(20), age int)
insert into userid_table (id, age)
values ('852801-1122', 29),
       ('132201-1233', 99),
       ('652001-1344', 49),
       ('751501-1455', 39),
       ('001501-1566', 14)
```

### Select With Formatting

```
select id as original_id, age,
       case when age > year(getdate())-2000 then '19' else '20' end + 
            substring(id,1,2) + 
            substring(id,5,2) + 
            substring(id,3,2) + 
            substring(id,8,4)
from userid_table
```

### Sample Output

```
| ORIGINAL_ID | AGE | NEW_ID       |
|-------------|-----|--------------|
| 852801-1122 |  29 | 198501281122 |
| 132201-1233 |  99 | 191301221233 |
| 652001-1344 |  49 | 196501201344 |
| 751501-1455 |  39 | 197501151455 |
| 001501-1566 |  14 | 200001151566 |
```